# How do I get add-apt-repository to work through a proxy passwd protected network?

Tags: apt, ppa, proxy, repository

I am trying to install ubuntu SDK but  when I enter this command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

I got an ppa error to check internet connection. So to over come this problem, I used these commands

```
export http_proxy=htt://username:passwd@proxyserver.net:port/export
sudo su  add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

But now I am getting this error:

```
No passwd entry for user 'add-apt-repository
```

Please help me out, as I really want to work on this SDK as I want to do something in open source world and want to develop something.
Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu Software Center is working......in my Ubuntu....

Comment: The command should be: **`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:<ppa-name>/ppa`**. You have an errant **`su`** in the middle.

Comment: After three days mind boggling searching with goggle, I found the actual code working .......1. u can change the mirror if u are getting the error of 403 forbidden using  "sudo sed 's@http://in\.archive\.ubuntu\.com/@http://archive.ubuntu.com/@' -i /etc/apt/sources.list" 2. then use terminal as a root using command  "sudo -s"  3. then use these three command as shown  = "export http_proxy=http://username:passwd@<proxy>:<port>
export https_proxy=http://username:passwd@<proxy>:<port> and now add the command for the package u wand to install.   thanks